# Hardhat estimatedGas error on smart contract deployment

Tags: contract-deployment, gas, gas-estimate, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I'm getting the following error when trying to deploy to BSC testnet:

`Hardhat Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"name":"ProviderError","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true}, method="estimateGas"`

Does somebody know what am I doing wrong? :( **Many thanks!**

hardhat.config.js file:

```
const secret = require("./environment/secrets.json");
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.9",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 300,
      },
    },
  },
  paths:{
    sources: "./blockchain/contracts",
    tests: "./blockchain/test",
    cache: "./blockchain/cache",
    artifacts: "./blockchain/artifacts"
  },
  networks:{
    testnet: {
      url: secret.testnetnode,
      accounts: [secret.privatekey],
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Probably there's a bug in the contract.